# Toggle radio selection with another radio selection and refresh button not page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button, toggle, jquery-mobile

Ok I Have a form with some questions as a radio option. If the first radio is selected as option yes, display the second radio option. if second radio option is also selected yes as the option, display third element (text box).

This functionality is working but what I can't get to work is if they change the first radio selection to no how can I hide and unset the second radio option (set option to no) and clear and hide the third element (text box) value.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$("#second_radio_div").hide("fast");
$("#third_element_div").hide("fast");

$("[name=first_radio]").change(function(){
    $("#second_radio_div").toggle($("[name=first_radio]").index(this)===1);

    if($("[name=first_radio]").index(this)===0) {
        //$('input:radio[name="second_radio_no"]').attr('checked',true); 
        //$('#second_radio').buttonset("refresh");
        //$('[name="second_radio"][value="no"]').attr("checked", true);
        //$('#second_radio').buttonset("refresh");
        $("#third_element_div").hide("fast"); // This works to hide the element
    }
});

$("[name=second_radio]").change(function(){
    $("#third_element_div").toggle($("[name=second_radio]").index(this)===1);
});
```

The HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <div>First Radio</div>
        <input type="radio" name="first_radio" id="first_radio_yes" value="yes" />
        <label for="first_radio_yes">Yes</label>

        <input type="radio" name="first_radio" id="first_radio_no" value="no" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="first_radio_no">No</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>


<div id="second_radio_div" name="second_radio_div">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <div>Second Radio</div>
            <input type="radio" name="second_radio" id="second_radio_yes" value="yes" />
            <label for="second_radio_yes">Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" name="second_radio" id="second_radio_no" value="no" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="second_radio_no">No</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third_element_div" name="third_element_div">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="text" name="third_element" id="third_element" class="default-value" value="If yes, provide date" />                
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#second_radio_div, #third_element_div").hide();

$("[name=first_radio]").change(function() {
    var show = $(this).val() == "yes";
    $("#second_radio_div").toggle(show);

    if (!show) {
        $('#second_radio_no').attr('checked',true); 
        $("#third_element_div").hide();
    }
});

$("[name=second_radio]").change(function() {
    $("#third_element_div").toggle($(this).val() == "yes");
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/N6qmr/

---

I think the main problem with what you had was this line:

```
$('input:radio[name="second_radio_no"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Should have been:

```
$('#second_radio_no').attr('checked', true);
```

Since there is no element with `[name="second_radio_no"]`

Comment: Hmm this is what I have working already, I want to work backwards as in if they un-select the second radio option (or select no) to hide and clear the value to the third element text box. If they un-select (or select no) on the first radio I want to hide and clear the value to the third element text box and select no on the second radio and hide it as well

Comment: based my selectors on the values of the checkboxes rather than the index. It feels better

Comment: I really do like this method just having a strange issue. When selecting the option yes (in an alert() ) it shows the value no and the opposite when selecting no it show the value yes. I have it in $(document).ready(function() in a form but I really don't think that's the issue. I'm also using jQueryMobile framework. Any thoughts as to why I get the previous value instead of the changed value?

Comment: that def seems odd. Can you post to jsfiddle?

Comment: Well I rewrote all my toggle function from what you had posted as I like the method you used (Big thanks), Here is the only other JS I'm running on the page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225110/jquery-toggle-sibling-on-focus-blur

Comment: I've added the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234406/selected-radio-option-using-change-not-working-as-expected-with-jqm-jquerymobi

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$("#second_radio_div").hide("fast");
$("#third_element_div").hide("fast");

$("[name='first_radio']").change(function() {
    $("#second_radio_div").toggle($("[name='first_radio']").index(this) === 0);

    if ($("[name='first_radio']").index(this) === 1) {
        $("#second_radio_no").attr("checked", true);
        $("#third_element_div").hide("fast"); // This works to hide the element
    }
});

$("[name='second_radio']").change(function() {
    $("#third_element_div").toggle($("[name='second_radio']").index(this) === 0);
});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/dVAzj/2/

Note that quotes are required around the 'value' in the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (`[name='value']`) selector.